# Where to store (premade) styles?

Tags: qgis

I have downloaded a set of premade styles (*.qml).

Where do I have to store this files for usage?

I am using QGIS 1.7 for windows.

---

I have found the following "solution": In the window "Layereigenschaften " (Layer-properties) click the button "Stil laden ..." (load style),now you can use this imported style. But I found no way to add these styles permanently to qgis-stylemanager

You can download this "open-street map"-styles from this site: http://www.sourcepole.ch/2010/2/28/spatialite QGIS-Styles für OpenStreetMap-Daten: Download

Answer (score 5):

QGIS symbols are stored in an XML format. The file is called **symbology-ng-style.xml**. You can import new symbols through Style Manager - Import. They will be added to Style Manager permanently.

QML files are a little different. They contain all the style information for a layer. In case of a more complex setup, a layer style can contain many different symbols for different types of features within a layer. QML files can be save using "Save style" and loaded using "Load style". They can also be assigned to a data source as it's "default style". Whenever you load the layer in ANY project, it will be assigned that default style.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the new option "Embed Layer and Groups" which imports layers from an existing project. You can create a project with your main "themes", save it centrally, and then reuse its layers over and over again.